# Python: Mock side_effect on object attribute

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a side_effect on a property? If I look at the Mock documentation it seems it's only possible on object methods.

I am trying to test the following:

```
def get_object(self): 
    try:
        return self.request.user.shop
    except Shop.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I want Shop to raise a DoesNotExist exception.

Guess maybe I wasn't clear enough but I am talking about the voidspace mock library.

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html

Comment: Is it possible to have a side_effect on a property?

Comment: Well I want to know if it's possible to have a side_effect (feature of the mock library) on the property of a mock object. In the documentation they only show examples doing this on methods. Since in my code shop doesn't get called the side effect isn't working. If you still have problems understanding the question I can elaborate it even more.

Comment: You might want to look at [pymox](http://code.google.com/p/pymox). Calling with side effects is one of its features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author made a blog post about this problem. I went for the first solution which looks like this:

```
class UserMock(Mock):
    @property
    def shop(self):
        raise Shop.DoesNotExist()
```

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2010_11_20.shtml#e1196

Answer (score 31):

It's worth noting that there is now the `PropertyMock` class:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> p = PropertyMock(side_effect=ValueError)
>>> type(m).foo = p
>>> m.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
ValueError
```

That example was [taken from the official site](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#raising-exceptions-on-attribute-access).

Comment: I know this post is 10 years old now, but that example is not correct for python 3. For anyone reading this, m.foo won't raise an error in the example given unless return_value is also given to the property mock e.g. p = PropertyMock(side_effect=ValueError, return_value=False)

Comment: I tell a lie... it's actually a hidden gotcha to this that is it won't work if the error you want to use is AttributeError. Use spec as mentioned in another comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to patch the related field using a **PropertyMock** as new_callable argument.

Example:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import mock
from django import models
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def has_pending_related(self):
        try:
            return self.related_field.is_pending
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return False

class FooTestCase(TestCase):
    # ...
    @mock.patch.object(Foo, 'related_field', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock)
    def test_pending_related(self, related_field):
        related_field.side_effect = ObjectDoesNotExist
        foo = Foo()
        self.assertFalse(foo.has_pending_related)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a property for it:

```
In [1]: class ShopDoesNotExist(Exception):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [2]: class User(object):
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def shop(self):
   ...:         raise ShopDoesNotExist
   ...:
   ...:

In [3]: u = User()

In [4]: u.shop
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ShopDoesNotExist                          Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on an instance of a class?

Comment: Why would you add a property to a single instance? If you want it conditional, simply use `if` in your property's method.

Comment: So I can replace shop during testing to raise that exception.

Comment: Ah, you want it only during testing... Then monkey-patch it from yout test code: `User.shop = property(lambda: raise DoesNotExist)`

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to raise exceptions from a lambda? Getting syntax errors when I do that. Seems your first answer wasn't to far off. Just found out the author of the plugin recommends to subclass the mock class and add a property like you showed in your example.

Comment: Indeed, you can't. Then simply do this: `def __fail(self): raise Exception` and `User.shop = property(__fail)`

Comment: Don't think adding properties to instances works either. https://gist.github.com/939447

Comment: Add it to the User object, not to an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, if you're trying to test for `AttributeError` as an `side_effect` you can use `spec` parameter and set it to empty list (i.e. `[]`). Say you're trying to create a `Mock` object that throws an `AttributeError` when accessing attribute `foo`:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
m = Mock(spec = [])
m.foo

# AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'foo'
```

See [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock):

> *spec: This can be either a list of strings or an existing object (a class or instance) that acts as the specification for the mock object. If you pass in an object then a list of strings is formed by calling dir on the object (excluding unsupported magic attributes and methods). **Accessing any attribute not in this list will raise an AttributeError.***