# Mock class attribute with side_efffect

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-mock

How can I raise exceptions while accessing an attribute of the mocked object?

I have tried to do the same with the following snippet,

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, PropertyMock


def function_to_call_one_to_one(model_instance):
    try:
        return model_instance.artist.name
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # calling `model_instance.artist` will raise `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception
        return "raised `ObjectDoesNotExist`"


class TestObjectDoesNotExist(TestCase):
    def test_artist_name(self):
        model_instance = MagicMock()
        model_instance.artist.name = "Michael Jackson"
        name = function_to_call_one_to_one(model_instance)
        self.assertEqual(name, "Michael Jackson")

    def test_artist_name_with_error(self):
        model_instance = MagicMock()
        model_instance.artist = PropertyMock(side_effect=ObjectDoesNotExist)
        res = function_to_call_one_to_one(model_instance)
        self.assertEqual(res, "raised `ObjectDoesNotExist`")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unfortunately, the test function, `test_artist_name_with_error(...)` has failed with message,

> AssertionError: <MagicMock name='mock.artist.name' id='140084482479440'> != 'raised `ObjectDoesNotExist`'

How can I write the unit-test for this case?

**Note:** I have seen this SO post, [Python: Mock side_effect on object attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353458/12578202), but, it doesn't work for me. I hope, this example is a *reproducible* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. Here's one part of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) that you might have overlooked:

> Because of the way mock attributes are stored you can’t directly attach a `PropertyMock` to a mock object. Instead, you can attach it to the mock type object.

This works:

```py
type(model_instance).artist = PropertyMock(side_effect=ObjectDoesNotExist)
```